# Check if a country reaches the threshold

Tags: prolog

Hi guys i'm new to prolog and i'm trying to understand something:

I have this database:

```
countries([belgium, france, germany, italy, luxembourg, netherlands]).
weight(france, 4).
weight(germany, 4).
weight(italy, 4).
weight(belgium, 2).
weight(netherlands, 2).
weight(luxembourg, 1).
threshold(12).
```

And I made this program to see if a list of countries have enough votes to get over the threshold and i want to use a predicate winning/1

```
winning([H|T]):-
 weight(H, N1),
 winning(T),
 weight(T, N2),
 N is N1 + N2,
 N>=X,
 threshold(X).
```

The program runs perfectly up untill the point it has to add up the voting power and conclude whether the votes reach the threshold.

Its difficult because I only want to use a predicate winning/1 can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is this homework? I ask because this would be easier using higher order predicates.

Comment: You also need an accumulator or  predicates that can accumulate results.

Comment: Missing the base case for the `winning/1` predicate. Think about what happens when you call `winning([])`.

Comment: yes it's homework but if you know how to fix this with higher order predicates please do tell.

Comment: The library solution in SWI-Prolog could be to use aggregate_all with sum and check that it is higher than the threshold. The other option is to start adding until you reach the threshold and succeed early or fail at the end; this will require a proper iteration over the list I suspect. You seem to be on the right way but there is a bunch of problems with your code at the moment.

Comment: @PauloMoura the base case is not missing. In the base case the predicate has to fail.

Comment: A recursive case without a base case always fails... you go from `winning([H|T])` to `winning(T)`...

Comment: @PauloMoura not if you succeed explicitly. `p([H|T]) :- ( q(H) -> true ; p(T) ).` Yes I know this is nitpicking and cheating. I don't like words like "always" because some people might think it means **always**. Regarding your first comment, `winning([])` must fail, if I understand the problem statement at all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not adding up N1 and N2 into N is because you are asking the weight-number for the entire Tail, when you should just get the weight of only the head of the Tail. Which at this point you don't have yet.

You want to create a separate (recursive) rule, winning/2 and call it from winning/1:

```
winning(Countries) :-
winning2(Countries,0).
```

In this separate winning/2 you call for the weight which you store in N and call back winning/2 recursively until N reaches the threshold.

```
winning2([],N) :-
    threshold(X),
    N >= X.

winning2([Country|Tail], N) :-
        weight(Country,X),
        NewN is X + N,
        winning2(Tail, NewN).
```